# Apache/nginx: pinned client certificates and FastCGI

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl, apache-2.4, fastcgi

Is it possible to have Apache or nginx accept **only** pinned client certificates and pass knowledge about the client's certificate to a [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com) response handler?